# Prevent Method Swizzling Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime, method-swizzling

I am trying to search to prevent the Method Swizzle in my current library but more or less every documentation or blog post that i found are about how to implement Swizzling.
There are couple of question that i have regarding Method swizzling that i could not find all across.

- How to detect the Method Swizzling at runtime?
- In case there is a Method Swizzle how to prevent it ?

I know the dangers of method swizzling and have already gone through the related posts here but could not find the related information to prevent it.

If there is any documentation or blog post that available on the above topics, I would really appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 9):

Avoiding method swizzling is simple; use functions rather than methods (i.e. do things the old-fashioned way without objects, in C++, or at least in Core Foundation). But if you're using the ObjC runtime, you can be swizzled.

You can in principle detect swizzling by caching all your `IMP` pointers, for example using `class_getMethodImplementation` in something like `+load` or maybe a C++ constructor on a global variable (which get run before `main()`), and then re-checking all your `IMP` pointers at various times to make sure they haven't changed.

That probably wouldn't be *too* hard, but it's difficult to imagine what all of this would achieve. If someone has your framework binary, it wouldn't be a major effort to to patch it to remove your check. Somewhere in the source code, there's got to be a `if (swizzled) { ... }`, and that's going to translate into a branch-if conditional instruction in the assembly. You stick a debugger on the system, wait for the branch to "ah! we're swizzled" to occur, note the point where it happens, and patch that byte to be "branch-if-not" or just add an unconditional jump.

Slowing that attack down, even a little, requires substantial obfuscation. There are techniques (that mostly don't work that well), but they only work by being kept secret. That's the difference between obfuscation and security.

Short answer is you really can't achieve this in any stable way. That means you either need a team devoted to constantly coming up with new, more advanced obfuscations and updating them regularly as new attacks emerge (i.e. how a company like Blizzard or Apple prevent hacking), or you'll need to find a way not to need this.

Simplest answer? Work mostly in C++ and use ObjC classes as little as possible (which will prevent swizzling, but not reverse engineering or patching). Or accept that swizzling is not avoidable.

(BTW, if there were even a "I'm willing to do whatever it takes" answer to this question, then Apple would just use that technique to make jailbreaking impossible. The fact that iPhones get jailbroken regularly suggests the difficulty of the problem.)

Comment: Thanks Rob. I really appreciate the detailed explanation. Was having somewhat similar idea about the check but it seems to be not very performance centric. But i do appreciate your answer.